# Deploying Vaadin Application

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, web-services, vaadin

Hello Folks,
            I am a new Java Developer , I have developed a web application developed in Java with  Vaadin frame work and SQL-server; using Intellij IDEA 14.0.1 IDE, I am almost at end of the development I have to deploy this application now, can you guide me, How to go with that and Requirement specifications.

Comment: - how do you know that you are in the end if you have never deployed it? :)
- What is the application server?
- What is the application packaging?

Comment: Have you read https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.environment.html? Where is there a problem?

Comment: Usually your IDE generates a .war file, which you can then just deploy on your servlet engine. Of course the config of any resources (Database, Ldap, Mail etc.) must be made.

Answer (score 0):

you need java hosting that is it .
also if you are just under testing and developing you can deploy it to one of the free ( PaaS ) sites like [openshift](http://www.openshift.com) or heruko .